# ERD Relationships

Tags: sql, erd

I'm having trouble setting up my database tables with these values. Is everything in the right tables, because, if they're not, could anyone please help me and show me the right? I just need clarification. Thanks!

[image: My database]

***Check out all the answers, they're all very helpful but I could only choose one!***

Comment: What troubles are you having? This is a very broad question. There is no "right and wrong" in setting up your database tables. If they match your needs then what is the issue?

Comment: AlbumTbl missing AlbumID? Just pointing out

Comment: @Volearix thanks for the reply. For the ArtistTbl, is it bad practice to have AlbumID and GenreID in the same table, linking to, the GenreTbl and the AlbumTbl. Sorry, I didn't really ask the question properly

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying. I'll post up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thought is that it's redundant to label every table with the suffix `Tbl`. We know its a table, there won't ever be any confusion about that. Calling it `users`, and `purchases`, for example, is sufficient. The same can also be said in regards to the primary keys of those tables. For example, you don't need to call the primary key id column of the Album table `AlbumID` because it can never be referenced outside of the context of the table to which it belongs. You can simply call it `id` instead.

You've got a number of extra columns in some tables that don't belong. The pattern I'm seeing might indicate you're not completely grounded in how relationships work. I will point out a couple of places where there is a mixup, and that should give you a solid enough grounding to review the rest of the tables and find the other errors.

Looking at the `UserTbl` table, you have the id of the purchase (`Purcahse_ID`). In real world terms, that means each user can only ever have one purchase, which is unlikely to ever be the case. More likely, a User **may have many** purchases. As a professor once told me, when deciding where to put the foreign key, the key always goes on the "many" side of the relationship. So, in this case, you will want to remove the `Purchase_ID` from `UserTbl`, and add a `User_ID` in the `PurchaseTbl`. That way, a user may indeed have many purchases, with each purchase containing the id of the user who made the purchase.

You have similar problems in the ArtistTbl and GenreTbl. See if you can determine how the relationships should look. Hopefully that makes a little more sense.

*Quick side note:* Unless your system is made to track slave labour, I believe the `ArtistID` in the `PurchaseTbl` should actually be the `AlbumID` instead, since the user is most likely purchasing an album, not a person.

Comment: When you say a user_id in the purchase table, do you mean the UserTbl primary key (id)? FK? Thanks for your answer also

Comment: @notc1 Correct, that's what that column would refer to. Usually (arguably, most of the time) you name your foreign key with the name of the table to which it references (so `user_id`, or `album_id`). So the primary key is typically named simply `id`, and the foreign key in the other table that references the aforementioned primary key is usually `[table name]_id`

Comment: Thank you, this is really good to know, I have always named it the same. Product_Id -- Product_Id, etc. Never done it the other way, id -- Product_Id

Comment: @notc1 Yeah, its not the end of the world if you call all your primary keys like that. But using the `id` (PK) and `[table name]_id` (FK) pattern is (again arguably) the most common naming convention you'll see out there. It might be important to know too that some systems and frameworks use that convention when trying to execute queries, so if you name your columns different than what they're expecting, the framework might have difficulty (and thus you).

Answer (score 2):

Your foreign keys look like they're mostly in the wrong tables.

- Does a user purchase an artist or an album? Probably an album, so the Purchase table should have an Album id instead of an Artist id.  The Purchase table should also have a User id to keep track of what user made the purchase.
- You could say that an artist belongs to a specific genre, but some artists switch genres every few years. It would probably be better to say an album has a genre, and put the Genre id foreign key in the Album table instead.
- The Genre table should not have an Album id. Each record in your genre table will not have one album that it's associated with. The relationship is the other way around. Each album belongs to a genre, so the Genre id foreign key should be in the Album table, as in the previous point.
- The Album table should have an Artist id foreign key, not the other way around.

In general, the way to get this right is to think about how many records in one table need to refer to a record in another table. If an artist releases ten albums, you can't put all ten album ids in one record in the artist table. You'd need ten columns for those ids, and that doesn't make sense. Instead, you want to track which artist recorded the album in the album table. That only takes one extra column for the artist id in the album table.

Comment: Thank you. This help me also, i'm understanding it alot more now, didn't think my tables were this wrong

Comment: @notc1 It's really just one mistake that you made several times. ;)

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need the suffix of `tbl` on your tables. They're in your database, we know they're tables, save yourself the typing. Second, you are referencing normalization. There are different tiers of normalization, some go too far in my opinion. Basically you want to connect your users to their purchases. Their purchases will link to albums, which have a genre and artist. If you have a relationship that can connect through many different ids, it's a good idea to link think in an intermediate table. You are heading the right direction with your tables, though not all of it is there yet. Have a look at this ERD and see if it makes sense to you. Combine this image with the above suggestions from other users and you'll get it sorted out. :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, great image to be able to undertsand the table compared to mine. I don't know which one to mark as the answer because they're all right

Comment: @notc1 Whichever one you feel best answers the question and/or helped you the most.

Comment: They all answered my question though, the image Volearix done out for me though was really helpful too because I'm comparing it to my own but yours and Bill the Lizard was descriptive in pointing out what was wrong